# Using a future object's data in a flutter list

Tags: list, flutter, dart, future

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureInfo = fetchInfo();
  }

  Future<Info> futureInfo;
  List<String> prices = [];
  List<String> duration = ["11 hours", "14 hours", "15 hours","12 hours", "10 hours", "8 hours",];
  List<String> airline = ["Middle East Airline", "Air Canada Airline", "Turkish Airline","Middle east Airline", "Turkish Airline", "Air Canada Airline",];
  List<String> destination = ['Beirut','Madrid'];
```

Hello 
I am still very new to flutter and I just wanted to know how can I use the data in the future object futureInfo in the list of prices where futureInfo is a parsed Json file into a class I have and I wanna be able to access it's attributes.
Also could you refer me to any documentations or videos that might help me learn the more technical part of flutter/dart not the more UI things.(ex: functions, states, variables ...)

Answer (score 1):

For understanding of future you should to go through this: https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

If you are very new then I would like to suggest you to go through this for Http call:  https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

Otherwise I would ask you to follow Bloc library for a lil deep knowledge to handle State changes. Bloc library is here: https://bloclibrary.dev/

Comment: Recommending BLoC in a question regarding futures that doesn't mention state management at all is pretty off-topic. Don't overload a new developer with information irrelevant to their question.

Comment: Alright, then your helping material is available in 1st 2 links. Future, async, await and https response.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you put info object

> Info info;

instead of

> Future futureInfo;

, then make your fetchInfo() method asynchronous like this,

```
fetchInfo()async{
//inside async method you can wait for any future to complete using await keywork

await operation1;
await operation2;

//then setState your Info object
setState(() {
  this.info = newValue;
});


}
```

Please it is easier if you post your full code for more clarity.

Comment: I have added code that might help. I want to get data from info which is a list and use it as list on its own to be displayed in cards. Any suggestions? I am currently using cards which take information from lists<string>. Is there a way to display them from a list of type data directly.

Comment: I checked so instead of `return Info.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));` just `setState(() {
  this.info = Info.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
});`

Comment: @RamiHoteit when you say 'I am currently using cards which take information from lists<string>.' which list<string> or card  do you mean List<Info> i will try to help if you make it a little bit clearer.

Comment: I have added my card widget build. I mean is there a way to use List<data> directly instead of using 4 separate lists to display things such as price and stuff.